# How to properly get heart rate from WatchKit?

Tags: swift, swift2, watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit

I am trying to simply display the last recorded heart rate from the Apple Watch. Below is what I am trying, but the `results` variable in the completion handler of `updateHeartRate` get millions of records and kills the app (almost seems like corrupt data or doing something incorrectly):

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    @IBOutlet var heartLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!

    let heartRateUnit = HKUnit.countUnit().unitDividedByUnit(HKUnit.minuteUnit())
    let heartRateQuantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate)

    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        super.willActivate()

        guard HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() else {
            heartLabel.setText("Not available")
            return
        }

        requestHealthKitAuthorization()
        queryHeartRateSample()
    }

    @IBAction func workoutMenuTapped() {

    }
}

private extension InterfaceController {

    func requestHealthKitAuthorization() {
        guard let heartRateQuantityType = heartRateQuantityType else {
            displayNotAllowed()
            return
        }

        let dataTypes = Set(arrayLiteral: heartRateQuantityType)

        HKHealthStore.sharedInstance?.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(nil, readTypes: dataTypes) {
            [unowned self] success, error in

            guard success else {
                self.displayNotAllowed()
                return
            }

            self.queryHeartRateSample()
        }
    }

    func displayNotAllowed() {
        heartLabel.setText("Not allowed")
    }

    func queryHeartRateSample() {
        guard let heartRateQuery = getHeartRateQuery() else { return }
        HKHealthStore.sharedInstance?.executeQuery(heartRateQuery)
    }

    func updateHeartRate(samples: [HKSample]?) {
        guard let heartRateSamples = samples as? [HKQuantitySample] else { return }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            guard let sample = heartRateSamples.first else { return }
            let value = sample.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(self.heartRateUnit)
            self.heartLabel.setText(String(UInt16(value)))
        }
    }

    func getHeartRateQuery() -> HKQuery? {
        guard let heartRateQuantityType = heartRateQuantityType else {
            displayNotAllowed()
            return nil
        }

        let heartRateQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: heartRateQuantityType,
            predicate: nil,
            limit: 100,
            sortDescriptors: nil) {
                [unowned self] query, results, error in
                guard let results = results as? [HKQuantitySample] else { return }
                self.updateHeartRate(results)
        }

        return heartRateQuery
    }

}

@available(iOS 8.0, *)
public extension HKHealthStore {

    class var sharedInstance: HKHealthStore? {
        if !HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
            return nil
        }

        struct Singleton {
            static let instance = HKHealthStore()
        }

        return Singleton.instance
    }

}
```

It does properly ask me to grant permissions, but still the update never gets triggered. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to use `HKAnchoredObjectQuery` to search only for new data added to **HealthKit** it avoid query all the data, so you can get the latest heart rate values in the following way once you have granted the permissions:

```
private let healthStore = HKHealthStore()

private let heartRateType = HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate)!
private let heartRateUnit = HKUnit(fromString: "count/min")

/**
 Start to measure the heart rate.
 */
func startToMeasure() {
    self.healthStore.executeQuery(self.createStreamingQuery()!)
}


/**
Create a query to receive new heart rate data from the HealthKit store.

- returns: The created query
*/
private func createStreamingQuery() -> HKQuery {
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(NSDate(), endDate: nil, options: .None)

    let query = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: heartRateType, predicate: predicate, anchor: nil, limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit)) {
        (query, samples, deletedObjects, anchor, error) -> Void in
        self.formatSamples(samples)
    }

    query.updateHandler = { (query, samples, deletedObjects, anchor, error) -> Void in
        self.formatSamples(samples)
    }

    return query
}

/**
 Format the samples received from HealthKit.

 - parameter samples: Some samples
 */
private func formatSamples(samples: [HKSample]?) {
    guard let samples = samples as? [HKQuantitySample] else { return }
    guard let quantity = samples.last?.quantity else { return }

    let value = Int(quantity.doubleValueForUnit(heartRateUnit))
    print("HeartRate: \(value)") 
}
```

The above code need to be integrated in some class or `UIViewController` you have. I have used in the above code a predicate to filter by date by you can remove it in case of not be relevant.

I hope this help you.

Comment: in Simulator Run this Code and Get Heart rate on it ?